# Помогите найти параметр

Tags: вёрстка, css

Помогите найти парметр на этом [сайте](http://www.mortalonline.com/screenshots) изменяющий вот эту высоту между верхним меню и листом (показана стрелками):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`mo.css`, строка 534:

```
#content-main { margin-top: 160px; }
```